# How to target text after input

Tags: text, target

I need to change text color in CSS. How do i target text Website like in this example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="website" name="website" value="website">Website<br>
```

What is the proper way, to wrap it in something like `<div>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping in the `<label></label>` does the trick.